# Ways to fetch ATA account in typescript?

Tags: anchor, typescript, associated-token-account, spl-associated-token-account

I have the following code that works fine with PDAs.

```
const escrow_pda = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("escrow"), fundraiser.publicKey.toBytes()], program.programId)[0];
const esc = await program.account.campaignEscrow.fetch(escrow_pda);
```

However, when I use the same fetch method on the following ATA, it returns **Error: Invalid account discriminator**

```
const vault_ata = (await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(provider.connection, fundraiser, mint_token, escrow_pda, true)).address
    const esc = await program.account.campaignEscrow.fetch(vault_ata);
```

What methods do you use to fetch data from the associated token account in typescript ?

**EDIT:**

How can I also get the token balance in Rust ?

```
//TokenAccount
pub donor_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`program.account` is used to help fetch and deserialize the custom accounts from your program.

To get the data for a Token Account in TS, use `getAccount` from `@solana/spl-token`:

```
import { getAccount } from "@solana/spl-token";

const TokenAccountData = await getAccount(connection, TokenAccountAddress)
```

You can get the Token Account data in Anchor using `ctx.accounts.donor_ata.amount` in your instruction logic.

Comment: I was able to figure it out this morning but forgot to update. Accepting answer!  Thank you ser!